# check if a folder is open (vba)

Tags: vba, directory

I am trying to check whether a specific folder is open or not using VBA . I have found this code:

```
Sub test1()
Dim OpenFold As Variant
Dim oShell As Object
Dim Wnd As Object
Dim strFolder

OpenFold = "mysubfolder"
strFolder = "U:\myfolder\" & OpenFold
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
If Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path = OpenFold Then 'this is where it gives me the error
Exit Sub ' Folder is open - exit this Sub
End If
Next Wnd
Application.ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=strFolder, NewWindow:=True
End Sub
```

But i am getting an error that the object is not supporting this property or method.

Any ideas?

Comment: At which line you get this error ?

Comment: It works, with a valid folder path.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the code it also helped me... I have checked
that the Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path does not apply to all Window object, for example IE, that is why it will give you an error message, I have done it by checking first if the windows is a Windows Explorer window. Code below.

Notes: 
`Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path` gives you full path string so you might want to compare it
with `strFolder`.

If you want to compare it to `OpenFold` variable you might want to use

```
Wnd.LocationName = OpenFold
```

Final Code:

```
Sub test1()
        Dim OpenFold As Variant
        Dim oShell As Object
        Dim Wnd As Object
        Dim strFolder

        OpenFold = "mysubfolder"
        strFolder = "U:\myfolder\" & OpenFold
        Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
            If Wnd.Name = "Windows Explorer" Then
               If Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path = strFolder Then Exit Sub 
            End If
        Next Wnd
        Application.ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=strFolder, NewWindow:=True
End Sub
```