# check if folder is open vba then show it on top

Tags: excel, vba

I have found a post and the code on stack overflow about [check if a folder is open (vba)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097610/9126536).

How about just show it on top of screen if the folder is already open ?

```
Sub test1()
    Dim OpenFold As Variant
    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim Wnd As Object
    Dim strFolder

    OpenFold = "mysubfolder"
    strFolder = "U:\myfolder\" & OpenFold
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
        If Wnd.Name = "Windows Explorer" Then
           If Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path = strFolder Then Exit Sub 
        End If
    Next Wnd
    Application.ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=strFolder, NewWindow:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: On Windows 10, you could add a line with `AppActivate OpenFold` and it should bring the File Explorer window on top.

Comment: I already try but it show me Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: I don't mind helping, but looking at your history, I don't see a single question marked as answered which gives me the impression that you don't value the help you are receiving from the community. I would ask you kindly to address this issue before going further.

Comment: You mine my answers still 0 on my blog ? Maybe I still need to learn more with you all for me can answer and help others on their problem, I will try to do that as I can

Comment: Sorry for late respond as I in very busy for this 2 days

Comment: I'm talking about [accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/372533)

Comment: Ohh I get it , will do that asap after I read and understand you link , thx

Comment: I just noticed that you did accept accept answers to your previous questions. Are you still looking for an answer to this question?